# iOS: is any solution to allow pod file # import some classes from project

Tags: ios, xcode, import, cocoapods

I want create pod library from most common class used in my most projects.
Is any way that pod classes #import some class in project?

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Have you got any solutions?

Comment: no solution for this problem!. hate apple for ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create private pods from your classes and use these in your projects. Have a look at this: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: no. i check it before. this is not answer. in pod classed installed on project we can not #import some files of projects